# Nodejs server send another object to client

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ajax, object

I'm just trying to send object from client to nodejs server

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: config.api.url,
  type: config.api.method,
  contentType: config.api.contentType, // application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
  dataType: config.api.dataType,       // JSON
  data: config.api.dataType === 'GET' ? {} : JSON.parse(tmp),
  headers: config.api.headers,
  success: (response) => { onSuccess(response); },
  error: (error) => { onError(error); }
});
```

Sent Data:

```
{
  sort: { name: 1 }
}
// I set name property by sort['name'] = 1; at js
```

But the server received:

```
{ 'sort[name]': 1 }
Nodejs server code:

exampleData = (req, res) => {
  var sort = req.body.sort;
  console.log(sort);       // undefined
  console.log(req.body);   // { ..., 'sort[name]': 1 }
}
```

Chrome Form Data:
[image]

So, I can't read object correctly like an object at js code.

My nodejs server code:

```
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: 1024*1024*20, type: 'application/json' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(cookieParser());
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Could you write down some your nodejs code?

Comment: Hi @AndrewLohr Like i said, I want to receive `{ sort: { name: 1 } }` like client object!

Comment: @NavyFlame I updated my code, please see change :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change `contentType` to `application/json` at your js code.

`contentType` are not the same type at server and client.

Comment: Changing the content-type header is harmful unless you change the content to match!

Comment: Hi @Quentin so, is it better to change client object?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
var x = { sort : {name:1} }

x["sort"] returns {name:1}
```

also

```
sort["name"] returns 1
```

similarly

```
sort["name"] = 1
```

is same as

```
sort = {name:1}
```

in your server it is not considering it as a JSON, so the problem is in what your server is seeing, it is not thinking it as a JSON, in the server make the content type to be as json (application/) and it will probably work.